# Stripe Payment Error in Event registration for multiple participants: "Property 'paymentIntentID' has not been set"

Tags: payment-processor, stripe, civicrm-event

I am finding an error in **Event registrations** for **multiple participants**.

The **Stripe Payment Processor** is raising the following error:

[error] Attempted to create **`paymentIntent`** from paymentMethod during doPayment failed: stdClass Object

(

```
[ok] => 1
[message] => 
[data] => Array
    (
        [requires_action] => 1
        [paymentIntentClientSecret] => pi_3MWNlLHijo63jtQl15z5UozV_secret_ZCGAKCKwVuI9NcLVBcU9ILQGy
    )
```

)

[error] Stripe Payment Error: Property **`'paymentIntentID'`** has not been set.

In the ****`civicrm_stripe_paymentintent`**** table a row has been recorded with the following column values:

identifier = NULL

contact_id = NULL

stripe_intent_id = '***pi_3MWNlLHijo63jtQl15z5UozV***'

status = '***requires_action***'

When I test the Event Registration in Test-drive mode, the registration process succeeds and the row recorded has the same NULL values in the columns mentioned above, but with the status **'*succeeded*'**.

Nevertheless, on the **Live registration** the payment process **fails**.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue for stripe for multiple registrations. There is a [work](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24781) for this issue.